# sum case when error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

I've written:

```
select 
    sum(case when is_trigger = "1" and when lh.ladder_change = "1" then 1 else 0 end),
    lh.member_id as "SFID"
From
  leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config as lc
  left join leeds.leenk_ladder_history as lh on lc.id = lh.ladder_config_id 

group by lh.member_id

limit 100;
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.member_id as "SFID"
From
  leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config as lc
  left join le' at line 2
```

I'm not sure what the error is. Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and when` is not valid SQL.  Drop the `when`.  You can further simplify the logic:

```
select sum(is_trigger = 1 and lh.ladder_change = 1),
       lh.member_id as SFID
From leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config lc left join 
     leeds.leenk_ladder_history lh
     on lc.id = lh.ladder_config_id 
group by lh.member_id
limit 100;
```

Notes:

- MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, no `case` is needed.
- You probably intend an `inner join` or to switch the tables.  You are aggregating by a column in the *second* table.  When there is no match, it is `NULL`.
- Double quotes are not an appropriate delimiter in SQL for strings.  Use single quotes for strings.
- I think the constants are really numbers, so no quoting is needed at all.

Comment: Hmm. Close but I actually want a sum(if()) -- hence me trying case when. 

I re-wrote to this: 

`select sum(if(is_trigger = 1 and lh.ladder_change = 1),1,0),
       lh.member_id as SFID
From leeds_so.leenk_ladder_config lc 
inner join 
     leeds.leenk_ladder_history lh
     on lc.id = lh.ladder_config_id 
group by lh.member_id
limit 100;`

but I'm still getting the error. Thoughts?

Comment: @AlissaSwartz . . . As I explain, you don't need `sum(if. . . )` or `sum(case . . . )`.  You can just sum the boolean expression.  This is a nice MySQL extension.  Try the code in this answer.